# Default primary key setter and getter generated by Service Builder

Tags: liferay, liferay-service-builder

I'm working with Liferay. When create an entity, we define one column as the primary key. Then I look at the entity model, I see some methods `setPrimaryKey`, `getPrimaryKey` as well as the setter and getter of the column that we defined as the primary key before. What is the difference of these methods? Do we need to use both methods once we add new entity into the table or just one

Comment: You  can use any of one when you are adding entity..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your project is built by many people. Some one designs entity and you only code view page. When you want to get or set primary key of entity but you don't know what column. If don't have setPrimaryKey or getPrimaryKey methods, do you look up in the code to find what column is primary key?